# Why does our blackheaded python wrap on herself?

Tags: behavior, reptiles

Our blackheaded python has been wrapping on our hand but mostly herself when we pick her up. It began when she would be trying to burrow under us if we were seated and picked her up, but now she does it even when we first get her out of her tank. She does it any time through her feed cycle and at any time during the year. She is just over 2 years and 5’5.